# Create customer in Magento 1.x via API REST

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, api

I am trying to create a new customers via an own API Model in Magento. Can't get the 'password' field from the POST request.

```
 /**
 * Create customer
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return string
 */
protected function _create(array $data)
{
    /** @var $validator Mage_Api2_Model_Resource_Validator_Eav */
    $validator = Mage::getResourceModel('api2/validator_eav', array('resource' => $this));
    $data = $validator->filter($data);

    var_dump($data); //There is no 'password' field.
```

Comment: Are you sure your codes are correct ? see this link `http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html`

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the native customer create REST API : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html ?

Comment: @sIiiS the link you posted is about SOAP API, OP is asking about REST

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism: yes, thanks, link changed

Comment: I got success in creating customer through REST. Is there any option of sending email with password in Magento after creation of customer (customer created with REST)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that there are other data. I assume ONLY password is missing.

If this is the case, make sure you send password as a parameter, Charles is a good tool here or HttpScoop, you can use wireshark as well.

If both happens, then you know, that the problem is in the code. Magento filters the password somewhere. Happy digging.